# why is argc returning 6 as opposed to 3?

Tags: c++, arguments, argc

I have following program and i am passing it 2 arguments at the command line as shown below. I was expecting the argc to be 3, but it prints it as 6. why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
void usage();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << argc << endl;
    if (argc != 3)
            usage();

    string regex = argv[1];
    string searchString = argv[2];

    cout << "regex: " << regex << " . searchString: " << searchString << endl;

    return 0;
}

void usage()
{
    cout << "Usage: ./stringmatch <regex> <searchString>" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Command line:

```
[jim@cola c++]$ ./stringmatch [yyyy\d\d\d]* yyyy1234
 6
 Usage: ./stringmatch <regex> <searchString>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your shell is expanding the glob pattern `[yyyy\d\d\d]*` so the actual number of arguments this results in depends on the contents of the current directory!

The `[yyyy\d\d\d]` becomes a character class matching the characters `y` and `d`, and the `*` matches anything that follows, so I'm guessing your current directory has 4 files that start with `y` or `d`. To see what it expands to, use `echo`:

```
$ echo [yyyy\d\d\d]*
```

To make it work as intended, quote the argument:

```
$ ./stringmatch '[yyyy\d\d\d]*' yyyy1234
```

Comment: How is shell treating [yyyy\d\d\d]* to? can you please explain more?

Comment: @Jimm try printing out argv and see what you get.

Comment: @Jimm It's called 'shell globbing'.

Comment: but \d is digit, so why is shell treating it as character 'd'?

Comment: A glob is not a regexp, and \ merely does escaping, nothing magical. Since there's no point escaping the letter `d`, `\d` is simply interpreted as `d`.

Answer (score 2):

`[yyyy\d\d\d]*` is expanded by the shell into multiple file names that match the pattern. Quote it to get 3.

Answer (score 2):

The shell resolves your command line to

```
./stringmatch [yd]* yyyy1234
```

which gives all files starting with either y or d plus yyyy1234. So if you have 4 files starting with either y and d plus yyyy1234 plus ./stringmatch will give exactly 6.

See [Filename Expansion and Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) for more information.

If you want just two arguments you must quote the first one with single or double quotes

```
./stringmatch '[yyyy\d\d\d]*' yyyy1234
```

Comment: this behavior of shell, is it because of presence of []?

Comment: The reason for this is because of character set `[]` and wildcard `*`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because your shell is expanding the arguments - wrap them in '' to prevent this.